# Can one rig run multiple different graphics cards?

Tags: litecoin, gpu-mining, mining-setup

I have some 7950 and some R280, can I connect them both on one rig? Will it work normally? Or does system require all GPUs to be same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you're good to go. You don't even have to connect them all through PCI-e. With *cgminer*, you can set the settings uniquely for each card. You can use any kind of adapter that would normally bottleneck GPU performance.

Comment: I've been reading about an 8 GPU limit (4 for dual cards). Any truth to this?

Comment: I'd assume that your weakest link would be the motherboard.

Comment: "You can use any kind of adapter that would normally bottleneck GPU performance" .. so using a PCIe x1 to PCIe x16 OR PCI to PCIe adapter would be ok?